# Mapping Columns when adding data to Excel Spreadsheet using Power Automate

Tags: excel, forms, power-automate

Apologies if this has been covered (I have searched extensively).

I am looking to create a flow in Power Automate which populates the outcomes of a Microsoft Form into an Excel Spreadsheet. I haven't had any issue with doing this in the past as previous forms have only required a small number of columns, so manually mapping them hasn't been a problem. On this occasion, I am looking at mapping over 150 columns and was wondering whether there was another way of mapping these other than manually searching for the corresponding value to the correct column.

I appreciate this might not be possible, but any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** It's cumbersome but manual is way to go. If you're looking into automation, that may take you longer to go that route (desktop Power Automation) for this specific project.

**Few questions and consideration for your application usage**:

- Will MS Form still useful after populating over 150 columns?
- Is-bidirectional data flow necessary between two (excel and Form)?

Excel Spreadsheet is great for smaller project, but even formula to correctly map to MS form and other application isn't straight forward.

**Suggestion**

- Look into another survey application that will give you the excel output/input mapping.
- Consider Excel import --> SharePoint List --> Power Apps (replacement of MS Form).